# Can ogr2ogr batch file run in cmd.exe?

Tags: convert, ogr2ogr, windows, services

I have very little experience in dealing with `ogr2ogr`, and currently I am trying to find out if there is a way I can automate batch conversion of .shp files to KML using windows services schedule.

So far I've got the below script In a .bat file based on what I have found on this site:

```
for /R %%f in (*.shp) do ogr2ogr -f "KML" %%~dpnf.kml %%f
```

I am able to run the batch file and convert successfully in FWTools shell, but windows cmd.exe tells me that 'ogr2ogr' is not recognised as a command. Is there any way I can set it up so that cmd.exe recognises it automatically and just runs the .bat file every time?

Comment: From the [GDAL Wiki](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries): **Important note: the FWTools binaries are not currently updated**... The GDAL/OGR version in FWTools is 1.7 from 2010. You should use the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w) or [GIS Internals](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk) GDAL binaries instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course. You just need to tell `cmd` where ogr2ogr lives.  This can be done in two ways.

**1)** Create a batch file to lauch cmd with the correct paths. aka `"C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.4.7\bin\setfwenv.bat"`

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\FWTools2.4.7\bin\setfwenv.bat"
ogr2ogr ...
```

**2)** You can add the paths that are set in `setfwenv.bat` into your system paths

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [C# application](https://github.com/AHartRC/Shape2Sql) that can instantiate a python environment from a batch script enabling the usage of OGR2OGR to convert ESRI Shapefiles (or other formats the application supports) into MS Sql Server (or other compatable formats).

This application looks at a specific directory for shapefiles and then processes those shapefiles into the previously mentioned batch script file so that way I can run multiple commands via one batch script.

The trick is how you format the batch file. Take a look at the output in the bin directory for any .bat file and you'll see a perfect example of what you're looking for.

```
@echo off

set SDK_ROOT=%~dp0
set SDK_ROOT=%SDK_ROOT:\\=\%

echo %SDK_ROOT%

if "%1" == "setenv" goto setenv

%comspec% /k "%SDK_ROOT%addrfeat_0_100.bat" setenv %1
goto processdata
goto exit

:setenv
@echo Setting environment for using the GDAL and MapServer tools.

if "%2"=="hideoci" goto hideoci

set ocipath=0
set _path="%PATH:;=" "%"
for %%p in (%_path%) do if not "%%~p"=="" if exist %%~p\oci.dll set ocipath=1

if "%ocipath%"=="0" goto hideoci
@echo WARNING: If you encounter problems with missing oci libraries then type:
@echo   SDKShell hideoci
goto setenv2

:hideoci
@echo Hiding the OCI plugin library.
if not exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional" mkdir "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional"
if exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll" move "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\ogr_OCI.dll" "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional\ogr_OCI.dll"
if exist "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll" move "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins\gdal_GEOR.dll" "%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins-optional\gdal_GEOR.dll"

:setenv2
SET "PATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python\osgeo;%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\apps;%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\csharp;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\csharp;%SDK_ROOT%bin\curl;%PATH%"
SET "GDAL_DATA=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal-data"
SET "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\plugins"
SET "PYTHONPATH=%SDK_ROOT%bin\gdal\python;%SDK_ROOT%bin\ms\python"
SET "PROJ_LIB=%SDK_ROOT%bin\proj\SHARE"

:processdata
@echo Processing File 1 of 100: tl_2015_01001_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01001_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 2 of 100: tl_2015_01003_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01003_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 3 of 100: tl_2015_01005_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01005_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 4 of 100: tl_2015_01007_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01007_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 5 of 100: tl_2015_01009_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01009_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 6 of 100: tl_2015_01011_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01011_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 7 of 100: tl_2015_01013_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01013_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 8 of 100: tl_2015_01015_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01015_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 9 of 100: tl_2015_01017_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01017_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 10 of 100: tl_2015_01019_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01019_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 11 of 100: tl_2015_01021_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01021_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 12 of 100: tl_2015_01023_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01023_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 13 of 100: tl_2015_01025_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01025_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 14 of 100: tl_2015_01027_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01027_addrfeat.shp"
@echo Processing File 15 of 100: tl_2015_01029_addrfeat.shp
ogr2ogr -progress -append -skipfailures -nln "addrfeat_2015" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=GEOMETRY" -lco "GEOM_NAME=Geom" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:4326" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=ANTHONY-PC;Database=MAF_Tiger;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" "D:\Census Data\Geo\tl_2015_01029_addrfeat.shp"

... and so on and so fourth

:exit
```